# TCA9509 level translating I2C bus repeater - can levels be the same?

Tags: i2c

The [TCA9509](http://www.ti.com/product/TCA9509), a nice little I2C bus repeater, has two supplies: \$V_{CCA}\$ and \$V_{CCB}\$, for supplying the two sides, master and slave respectively.

I can't tell if it can be used as a normal bus repeater for an all-\$5V\$ bus, or whether the master bus must be 1 volt lower. The datasheet seems annoyingly ambiguous: the expression \$V_{CCA} \leq (V_{CCB} - 1)\$ appears in the "Electrical Characteristics" section, some of the Application examples and even on the main page, as linked above, under *Parametrics*:*Supply restrictions*, as shown:

[image: Screenshot from http://www.ti.com/product/TCA9509]

Obviously not actually from the datasheet, but someone thought it important enough to extract it and put it on the main page. All the examples in the datasheet ensure that \$V_{CCA}\$ is at least a volt lower than \$V_{CCB}\$, and the constraint is mentioned multiple times in the datasheet.

The description says:

> This TCA9509 integrated circuit is an I2C bus/SMBus
>   Repeater for use in I2C/SMBus systems. It can also
>   provide bidirectional voltage-level translation (up-
>   translation/down-translation) between low voltages
>   (down to \$0.9V\$) and higher voltages (\$2.7V\$ to \$5.5V\$)
>   in mixed-mode applications. This device enables I2C
>   and similar bus systems to be extended, without
>   degradation of performance even during level shifting.

The "*It can also provide...*" wording sounds awfully like level-shifting is an additional, optional capability. The actual "Recommended Operating Conditions" - where you'd expect restrictions like this to appear - doesn't mention it or suggest it (max value for both is \$5.5V\$, not \$V_{CCA}=4.5V\$, \$V_{CCB}=5.5V\$, as you'd expect if this was a real limit).

Does anyone know the truth, please? I want to run both sides at \$5V\$, plain and simple. Is there something I've missed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can. That's the repeater mode *without level translation* that you mention.

Comment: Wonder why they put that condition/restriction so prominently on the web-page?  Anyway, good news! - because I'd bought a packet of them before realizing this might be a problem :-)  Thanks, Marcus

Comment: I really don't see why you think any of this was ambiguous; "can also provide" is very clear, imho.

Comment: Because every single mention of VccA vs VccB, shows the same inequality. It's on the main page as a "Supply Restriction". Every example shows VccB more than a volt higher than VccA. And "can also provide" (which is the only place that hints about it) *is* insufficient: "X can provide Y" doesn't require that "X can't *not* provide Y". I thought it suggestive (as stated in the question) but in the face of the other evidence, it's implied weakly rather than asserted.

Comment: Can't find that "supply restriction" you mention aside from a table that shows *other* devices... And "X can **also** provide Y" is pretty clear, again.

Comment: "Supply restrictions" is at bottom of the main page I linked to, under "Parametrics". I've added a screenshot and a note to the question to clarify. This issue was brought to me by a co-worker, who said "where does it actually say same levels are supported?" and I couldn't answer him - hence the question. On the semantics of *can*: hmm, if I said "an electron is a particle for use in making universes. It *can also provide* negative charge in electrostatic applications"; that's a true statement, but we know we can't infer that electrons are non-negative in, say, magnetics applications.